# "To make a lie" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm reading a book and I bumped into this sentence:

> He had aged well; his face was lined and wrinkled like every
>   other resident of Hilltop, but there was a youthfulness about
>   him, a certain quality of energy and vitality that seemed
>   to make a lie of all the wrinkles.

So my question is: what is the exact meaning of the structure "to make a lie of" in this context. It is not in any dictionary.

Thanks!

Comment: Please cite sources. Right now, your sentence redirects to ...here.

Comment: It parses no differently than to make a cake of.  Make has its normal definition. So does lie.   In other words if you believed what the wrinkles might suggest about the man's energy and vitality, you'd be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [**Lying and Teaching the Truth**](https://www.deborahhage.com/articles/lying.html) by Deborah Hage, one finds

> The actions make a lie of the loving words.

This obviously means 'The cruel / uncaring actions reveal the loving words to be deceitful.'

Shakespeare, in Othello Act 3 has

> Think'st thou I'ld make a lie of jealousy

meaning 'Do you think I'd say this jealousy didn't actually exist?'

And here, 'that seemed to make a lie of all the wrinkles' means 'that seemed to prove that the wrinkles were bearing false testimony about his age / had appeared far too early'.

Answer (score 1):

**to make a lie** can be found in the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/108036?redirectedFrom=make%20a%20lie#eid39431022):

> a. An act or instance of lying; a false statement made with intent to
>   deceive; a criminal falsehood. Phrase, to tell (†formerly **to make) a
>   lie**.

As in: ['Pshaw, It's Me Grandson': Tales of a Young Actor](https://books.google.com/books?id=KUNOAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA36&dq=%22to%20make%20a%20lie%22&pg=PA36#v=onepage&q=%22to%20make%20a%20lie%22&f=false) 2006

> Before Clay can finish his line, Rosebud reaches around and bites his
>   chin sharply, as if to make a lie of his claim.

Comment: +1 I have heard this from people from the American South. "to make a lie" seems fossilized in some parts of the Anglophone sphere.